# c# comp sci , bool/if/else statements not working as intended

Tags: c#

So im in my first month of class and we just got our 2nd lab for creating a 3 digit code lock in c# console. I am wanting the user to input 3 digits at the same time (and not seperately) and for some reason my code will allow any answer as long as one of the digits is correct

Example: `codepassword` is `111` and `user` inputs is `1`, it will still use the if statement for it being correct:

```
int password = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int correct = 111;
bool passwordb = Convert.ToBoolean(password);
bool right = Convert.ToBoolean(correct);
if (passwordb == right)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Access Granted");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Access Denied, Try again");
}
```

Comment: anything non-zero is "true", so if you convert to boolean and then compare, you are comparing true == true, which is, of course, true.

Comment: Just avoid using the `Convert` class entirely. It has a very poorly designed API surface that just means you get runtime errors instead of compile-time errors.

Answer (score 1):

Why all the Convert.ToBoolean? All you need is

```
   int password = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int correct = 111;

    if (password == correct)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Access Granted");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Access Denied, Try again");
    }
```

Comment: see thats what i had originally tried and it gave me an error, aha now i realize what i did, i originally didnt put == just = and i assumed it was a different error thank you

Comment: I'm always astonished by how rarely people describe the error when they say something "gave me an error."

Comment: @JGray - you should see if you can work out what was going on with your posted code, the one with all the `Convert.ToBoolean`s